# iTextSharp create PDF with stamper

Tags: asp.net, itext

I need a way I can create a new PDF with a Stamper (I'll admit Im new to itextsharp and I don't fully understand what a Stamper is).
So far Im creating TextFields by editing previous pdf documents with a stamper:

```
using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(new PdfReader(Server.MapPath("~/PDFs/"+TemplateId+".pdf")), File.Create(Server.MapPath("~/PDFs/addacro.pdf"))))
{              
    iTextSharp.text.pdf.TextField tf = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.TextField(stamper.Writer, new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(0, 0, 595, 842), "Vertical");
    stamper.AddAnnotation(tf.GetTextField(), 1);
    stamper.Close();
}
```

Simply how would I do the same thing for a new doc (non-existing)

Thank you

**EDIT**

I know that those are the constructors from http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/5.5.9/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfStamper.html

```
PdfStamper()
PdfStamper(PdfReader reader, OutputStream os)
PdfStamper(PdfReader reader, OutputStream os, char pdfVersion) 
PdfStamper(PdfReader reader, OutputStream os, char pdfVersion, boolean append)
```

all which read a document seem to have an output stream...

Comment: To create a pdf from scratch using itext 5, you use an itext `Document` with an itext `PdfWriter`. A `PdfStamper` is a class for *stamping* additions onto an existing pdf. But you say you are *new to itextsharp*. In that case you should switch to and learn the new itext 7 instead of the old itext 5.

Comment: Thank you! Im an intern and they use itextsharp here :/ why didn't you post this as an answer?

Comment: An answer should go more into detail but I'm currently on a smart phone and going into detail here is quite a pita. I can make that an actual answer later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a pdf from scratch using itext 5, you use an itext `Document` with an itext `PdfWriter`. A `PdfStamper` is a class for stamping additions onto an existing pdf.

For a text field similar to your stamper-based example:

```
Document document = new Document();
Stream stream = new FileStream(@"emptyTextField.pdf", FileMode.Create);
PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
document.Open();

TextField tf = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.TextField(pdfWriter, new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(0, 0, 595, 842), "Vertical");
pdfWriter.AddAnnotation(tf.GetTextField());

document.Close();
```

The main difference being that the `PdfWriter.AddAnnotation` does not take a page number parameter but assumes the page currently worked on, i.e. the currently last page of the document.

---

You say you are new to itextsharp. If you were not bound to that iText v5 by your job, you had better switch to and learn the new itext 7 instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!